# INVALID_ENUM using glew

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, game-engine, glew

I'm currently trying to program a litte game in c++ using SDL and glew. My problem is that whenever I try to use on of glew's functions (for example: glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)), I get this error: GL_INVALID_ENUM.

That is how I create the window:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
```

That's the way how I initialize glew:

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum res = glewInit();
if (res != GLEW_OK) fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
```

I tried to disable glewExperimental aswell but it changed nothing.

Comment: Well, `glMatrixMode` itself is an invalid API call in a ***core*** OpenGL 3.2 context. The enumerant `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX` is just icing on that cake. You need to use a *compatibility* profile if you want to use deprecated parts of the API like that. `glMatrixMode` is also not a glew function.

Comment: How do I change to compatibility profile?

Comment: I found it (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY). But I still get the error.

Comment: Ok. I was wrong. This solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't edit the title to include "solved". Add an answer so that the next person with the same problem can see what the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the core profile of OpenGL instead of using the compatibility profile to use deprecated parts of API. To solve this should replace

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
```

with:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);
```